# Cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer

Tags: rust

I have the following code

```
pub struct PropertyDeclarationBlock {
    pub declarations: Arc<Vec<(PropertyDeclaration, PropertyDeclarationImportance)>>
}

impl PropertyDeclarationBlock {
    pub fn select_declarations(&self) -> Arc<Vec<PropertyDeclaration>> {
        Arc::new(self.declarations.clone().map_in_place(|p| {
                                                        let (declaration, _) = p;
                                                        declaration
                                                        }))
    }

}
```

I want to be able to call .select_declarations() on a PropertyDeclarationBlock and have it return a clone of the declarations but instead of it being a Arc Vec (PropertyDeclaration, PropertyDeclarationImportance) be only a Arc Vec PropertyDeclaration, in other words returning a a vector of PropertyDeclaration instead of the previous tuple.

The previous won't compile as I am getting the following error:

```
error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
Arc::new(self.declarations.clone().map_in_place(|p| {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

From what I understand, since the function take self as a parameter it will take ownership of it. Since I'd rather have the function burrow self I use the &.

**EDIT**

Here is the error message after implementing the new function:

```
error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
Arc::new(self.declarations.iter().map(|&(declaration, _)| declaration).collect())
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: attempting to move value to here (to prevent the move, use `ref declaration` or `ref mut declaration` to capture value by reference)
Arc::new(self.declarations.iter().map(|&(declaration, _)| declaration).collect())
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried applying the ref keyword before declaration as suggested by the error message but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.declarations.clone()` clones the `Arc`, while I believe you intended to clone the `Vec`. To resolve the call to `map_in_place`, the compiler automatically dereferences the `Arc` to be able to call the method, which is defined on `Vec`. The compiler knows how to dereference the `Arc` because `Arc` implements [`Deref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html). `deref` returns a borrowed pointer, and this is where the error comes from. To clone the `Vec`, we must explicitly dereference the `Arc`: `(*self.declarations).clone()`.

However, [`map_in_place`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.map_in_place) is not suitable in this case, as `(PropertyDeclaration, PropertyDeclarationImportance)` doesn't have the same size as `PropertyDeclaration` (unless `PropertyDeclarationImportance` has a size of zero, which is probably not the case), which is required per the docs. It fails with a message similar to this:

```
task '<main>' failed at 'assertion failed: mem::size_of::<T>() == mem::size_of::<U>()', /build/rust-git/src/rust/src/libcollections/vec.rs:1805
```

Here's a proper implementation:

```
impl PropertyDeclarationBlock {
    pub fn select_declarations(&self) -> Arc<Vec<PropertyDeclaration>> {
        Arc::new(self.declarations.iter().map(|&(declaration, _)| declaration).collect())
    }
}
```

Here, we use [`iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) on the `Vec` to create an iterator over the vector's items. This returns an [`Items`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Items.html), which implements [`Iterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) on immutable references.

Then, we use [`map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.map) to lazily map `(PropertyDeclaration, PropertyDeclarationImportance)` to `PropertyDeclaration`. Note how we destructure the tuple *and* the reference in the closure's parameter list (this works in `fn`s too) instead of using a `let` statement.

Finally, we use [`collect`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.collect) to create a new collection container for this sequence. `collect`'s result is generic; it can be any type that implements [`FromIterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html). `Vec` implements `FromIterator`, and the compiler infers `Vec` from the method's signature.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I am still getting a similar error. I will edit my question with the new error message.

Comment: I'm not getting this error on play.rust-lang.org. Try getting a more recent build; closures are changing lately.

Comment: I'm was coding a pull request for Servo. The version of Rust is fixed by Servo. I'll check what version it is using.